# <double> RegEx catching IP addresses

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using a parser, which mistakenly parses IP addresses as double values. Since I know nothing about regular expressions, take a look:

```
AddRule<double>("!!float", @"[-+]?(0|[1-9][0-9_]*)\.[0-9_]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?",
            m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value.Replace("_", "")), null);
AddRule<double>("!!float", @"[-+]?\._*[0-9][0-9_]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?",
            m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value.Replace("_", "")), null);
AddRule<double>("!!float", @"[-+]?(0|[1-9][0-9_]*)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)",
            m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value.Replace("_", "")), null);
```

Is there some quick way to fix that? (The error is on the first lambda expression)

Comment: No, there's not. The problem is the first regular expression, which basically says "0 or any number starting with 1 to 9, followed by a dot and possibly nothing". You could change that, but how are we supposed to know whether that would or wouldn't break anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this does the trick.

```
AddRule<double>("!!float", @"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$",
            m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value.Replace("_", "")), null);
```